# Wordpress Custom Post Type infinite redirect loop using Advanced Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

Using Wordpress 3.1 and the latest Advanced Permalinks and Custom Post Type UI i have created a custom post type called 'people'. The url pattern for all children of this post type are people/jim, however when i view post i get stuck in an infinite redirect loop. This only happens when I use pretty permalinks, not when id's are used.

The permalinks structure used on Advanced Permalinks are:

### Common Settings

Custom Structure: %postname%

### Post

%postname%

- Wordpress is redirecting the custom post type to itself instead of translating it as ?people=jim.
  I have tried defining the post types myself in functions.php and then doing a flush but that doesn't seem to fix the issue as others have found. Greatly appreciate any fix!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of logging and debugging, I found that the function that was causing the infinite redirect was `function the_posts($posts)`. If you comment out everything from `if (is_single () && count ($posts) > 0)` to just before `remove_filter ('the_posts', array (&$this, 'the_posts'));`, it ceases the infinite redirect, and seems to still function fine! The only side-effect is that if you go to `/jim/` it will redirect you back to `/people/jim/` (rather than just giving you a 404). For me, that was Good Enough, since it fixed this problem.

So, again, within `advanced-permalinks.php`, search for `function the_posts` and then comment it so it looks like the code below.

Why does this break it? Because the custom post type is_single and doesn't match any rules, apparently, which makes APL send it back for re-direction... endlessly. Blah. Perhaps there is a more clever way to do this, to check if it is a custom post type, or whatever, but just disabling it seemed to do fine by me.

```
/**
 * Hook that is called when a post is ready to be displayed.  We check if the permalink that generated this post is the
 * correct one.  This prevents people accessing posts on other permalink structures.  A 301 is issued back to the original post
 *
 * @return void
 **/

function the_posts ($posts)
{

/* DISABLED CODE BELOW:

    // Only validate the permalink on single-page posts
    if (is_single () && count ($posts) > 0)
    {
        global $wp, $wp_rewrite;


        $id = $posts[0]->ID;  // Single page => only one post

        // Is this a migrated rule?
        $migrate = get_option ('advanced_permalinks_migration_rule');

        if ($migrate)
        {
            if (isset ($migrate[$wp->matched_rule]) && substr (get_permalink ($id), strlen (get_bloginfo ('home'))) != $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
            {
                wp_redirect (get_permalink ($id));
                die ();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the permalink for the post
            $permalink = $this->get_full_permalink ($id);

            // Generate rewrite rules for this permalink
            $rules = $wp_rewrite->generate_rewrite_rules ($permalink);

            // THIS IS ESPECIALLY PROBLEMATIC PART FOR CUSTOM POSTTYPES

            // If the post's permalink structure is not in the rewrite rules then we redirect to the correct URL

            if ($wp->matched_rule && !isset ($rules[$wp->matched_rule]))
            {
                wp_redirect ( get_permalink ($id));
                die ();
            }
        }
    }
    DISABLED CODE ABOVE */

    remove_filter ('the_posts', array (&$this, 'the_posts'));
    return $posts;
}
```